# Vue.js does not show symbols

Tags: vue.js

i'm learning Vue, and in first lesson this code not working, whats wrong? Vue update?

```js
new Vue({
el: '#app',
    data: {
    name: 'Vue!'
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to use the data property in vue

This is used when you are using vue in a root Vue instance

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      name: 'Vue !'
    }

});
```

This is used when you are using vue components

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'Vue !'
    }
  }
});
```

Are you using components?

Comment: All ok, thanks for reply, i have problem in Chrome - http://prntscr.com/lzkz0s http://prntscr.com/lzkz69 - Firefox

Comment: You are using two different source code on both. Kindly mark my answer as working then.